# CSS3 Multiple Columns и position: absolute

Tags: css3

Привет.

Я использую CSS3 Multiple Columns.
Дочерние элементы колонок имеют position: relative, а внутри них могут быть стрелки с position:absolute.

**Проблема:** CSS колонка обрезает стрелку с абсолютным позиционированием.

https://jsfiddle.net/k4ucr72h/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `z-index: 1` к `.countArrow` как вариант

**Правка:**

Немного изучил это странное поведение. Я так понимаю, что это баг всех хромибраузеров, и корректно в данном плане css3 мультиколонки работают только в firefox.

Баг репорт - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84030

Другой пример бага с первой буквой - http://jsfiddle.net/5tX4A/4/

Все, что выходит за пределы колонки, обрезается как-будто действует свойство overflow: hidden;

Советую вам просто переверстать список более привычными методами и не углубляться в это.

Comment: z-index не работает

Comment: У меня работает: https://jsfiddle.net/k4ucr72h/1/

Comment: А какой браузер вы используете?
У меня ваш пример так же не работает http://i.gyazo.com/01dfe13a8a19ec4cf95f577be2d80648.png

Comment: @ТимофейПетров дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вложи в подсказку элемент с position:fixed и z-index'ом и помести всё внутрь него.
https://jsfiddle.net/k4ucr72h/3/

```
<div class="countArrow"><div>Найдено&nbsp;<span>6700&nbsp;товаров</span></div></div>

.countArrow {
  position: absolute;
  top:-7.5px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.countArrow div{
  position: fixed; 
  color: #fff;
  background: #36363d;
  padding: 0px 10px 0 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  ...
```

UPDATE: Я не прав. Это работает только если нет скролла. Иначе получается фигня...

Answer (score 0):

Решение есть на [англоязычном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597938/css3-multiple-columns-and-positionabsolute/51994003#51994003). Добавлением в элементы списка свойства

```
break-inside: avoid;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Не забудь добавить префиксы, по сути проблему решает только backface-visibility Так что можно обойтись только им.

В причинах я не разбирался, времени нет, но если кто знает будет интересно узнать